# Derivative of simple fraction

Tags: derivatives

What is the fastest way of finding the derivative of:

$\frac{x}{x+K}$ (simplified form)

is there a substitution I miss or does the quotient rule the job here? There should be a quick way of finding the derivative

Comment: Quotient rule works.

Answer (score 0):

Quotient rule works, although here's a probably slightly faster method.

Let $$\begin{align}y &= \dfrac{x}{x+K}
\\\ln y &= \ln x - \ln(x+K)
\\&\text{Differentiating w.r.t.} x
\\\dfrac{1}{y}\dfrac{dy}{dx} &= \dfrac{1}{x} - \dfrac{1}{x+K}
\\\dfrac{dy}{dx} &= y \left(\dfrac{1}{x} - \dfrac{1}{x+K}\right)
\\ &= \dfrac{x}{x+K}\left(\dfrac{1}{x} - \dfrac{1}{x+K}\right)
\\&= \dfrac{1}{x+K}-\dfrac{x}{(x+K)^2}
\\&= \dfrac{x+K-x}{(x+K)^2}
\\&= \dfrac{K}{(x+K)^2}\end{align}$$

Comment: @Amzoti Oops, thanks for pointing that out. :)

Answer (score 0):

by th quotient rule we get
$y'=\frac{x+K-x}{(x+K)^2}=\frac{K}{(x+K)^2}$